# Implementing relationships in CakePHP Model

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am new to Cake and am trying to implement the Model layer as best as I can by using the bake script.

The implementation of my DB relationships has me a little worried though.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `model_base_test`.`entrys` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entry_year` INT(2) NOT NULL,
  `contact_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `division_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `category_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `entry_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `scale` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ootb` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `scratch` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `theme` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `medal_id` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_id` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_entries_contacts_idx` (`contact_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_entries_groups_idx` (`category_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_entries_medals_idx` (`medal_id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `entry_id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_entrys_divisions_idx` (`division_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_entries_contacts`
    FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`)
    REFERENCES `model_base_test`.`contacts` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_entries_groups`
    FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`)
    REFERENCES `model_base_test`.`categorys` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_entries_medals`
    FOREIGN KEY (`medal_id`)
    REFERENCES `model_base_test`.`medals` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_entrys_divisions`
    FOREIGN KEY (`division_id`)
    REFERENCES `model_base_test`.`divisions` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `model_base_test`.`scores` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `judge_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `entry_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `criteria` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `possible_points` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_possible` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `raw_score` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `score_adjustment` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `weighted_score` DECIMAL(5,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_scores_entries_idx` (`entry_id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_scores_entries1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`entry_id`)
    REFERENCES `model_base_test`.`entrys` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

With the above tables and constraints as example, how best can I implement with Cake?  The above is an optional one-to-many relationship, i.e. there is not necessarily a Score row for the mandatory Entry row.

Comment: It should be optional by default when you bake it.

Comment: Thanks - so a different question on the same lines.  Since bake does  not distinguish this, is there anything required for a mandatory one-to-many relationship?

Comment: Just additional code beyond baking. Don't mean to sound flippant, but because **mandatory** is a business rule, it needs to be coded accordingly. For example, add the business rule: for every Entry there needs to be at least 2 Scores (hence a mandatory 1:2 relation). You would need to make sure anytime an Entry was created, there would have to be 2 Scores. If your application allows a Score to be deleted (or disassociated from an Entry), you need to make sure that there would still be 2 left after deletion.

Comment: understand.  thanks for your attention and expertise.  I will keep that in mind as I work through Model.